# FATAL: access method "btree" does not support unique indexes, Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64 GNU/Linux & postgresql-9.4.4

Tags: postgresql

```
xxxxx@user:/tmp$ sudo -u postgres /usr/local/pgsql/bin/initdb -D 

/usr/local/pgsql/data/
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
creating configuration files ... ok
creating template1 database in /usr/local/pgsql/data/base/1 ... FATAL:  access method "btree" does not support unique indexes
child process exited with exit code 1
initdb: removing contents of data directory "/usr/local/pgsql/data"
```

Comment: pls provide postgresql Version information and OS specific infos

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04   x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux & postgresql-9.4.4

Comment: Ubuntu what version? pls edit original question

Comment: Something's really broken there. Please upload your `config.log` from the compilation somewhere and link to it here. Also, if you `make clean && make && sudo make install` does the issue go away?

Comment: Thanks, issue solved by $sudo make clean